# Where is the mistake?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the IVP 
$$x'(t) = 1 + (x(t))^2,\quad x(0) = 0.$$ 
Backward
Euler method is applied to this problem the numerical solution $x_1$
at time $t_1 = h$.Then I found 
$$x_1= \frac{1+ (1- 4h^2)^{1/2}}{2h}$$
but solution say $$X_1=\frac{2h}{1 +(1-4h^2)^{1/2}}$$

Where is the mistake?
$$\begin{align*}
X_{n+1}= X_n +hX'_{n+1} &\implies X_{n+1}= X_n +h( 1 +(X_{n+1})^2)\\
&\implies x(h)= X(0)+h(1+X(h)^2)\\
&\implies hx(h)^2 -X(h)+h\\
&\implies  X_1= \frac{1+(1-4hh)^{1/2}}{ 2h} &\text{(by root finding formula)}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Without seeing the work it is hard to find a mistake.

Comment: It seems you have a few problems with the backward Euler method. Do you have a teacher you can go to?

Answer (score 3):

Small problems: you go back and forth between $x$ and $X$ and $X_1$.

Also, I think you left out the "$=0$" on the next-to-last line.

Bigger problem: a quadratic equation (generally) has *two* solutions. You have left out the $\pm$. Then you might meditate on whether $${2h\over1+(1-4h^2)^{1/2}}{\rm\quad and\quad }{1-(1-4h^2)^{1/2}\over2h}$$ are all that different.